# how to call more than one soap service in java

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I have to make a java simulator to call multiple soap requests in java. There are 4 Soap Requests in the WSDL. I am able to call one request by hardcoding the XML in java, but I want a dynamic approach of calling soap services.
Didnt find anything on internet.

```
package sisII.JNDI;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import javax.xml.soap.*;

public class MessageConnector {

    public String callService (String IDNumber) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, SOAPException {
        String urlString = "http://wsdl_url";
        URL urlForInfWebSvc = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection UrlConnInfWebSvc = urlForInfWebSvc.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnInfWebSvc = (HttpURLConnection) UrlConnInfWebSvc;
        httpUrlConnInfWebSvc.setDoOutput(true);
        httpUrlConnInfWebSvc.setDoInput(true);
        httpUrlConnInfWebSvc.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
        httpUrlConnInfWebSvc.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpUrlConnInfWebSvc.setRequestProperty("Host", "localhost");
        httpUrlConnInfWebSvc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");
        httpUrlConnInfWebSvc.addRequestProperty(header_credentials);
        OutputStreamWriter infWebSvcReqWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(httpUrlConnInfWebSvc.getOutputStream());
        String infWebSvcRequestMessage = 
            "   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:req=\"http://def" xmlns:com=\"http://xyz" xmlns:aler=\"http://abc"> " +
                      " <soapenv:Header/>" +
                       "<soapenv:Body>" +
                       ......
                       "</soapenv:Body>" +
                    "</soapenv:Envelope>"  ;

        infWebSvcReqWriter.write(infWebSvcRequestMessage);

        infWebSvcReqWriter.flush();
        BufferedReader infWebSvcReplyReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpUrlConnInfWebSvc.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        String infWebSvcReplyString = "";
        while ((line = infWebSvcReplyReader.readLine()) != null) {
            infWebSvcReplyString = infWebSvcReplyString.concat(line);
            }
        infWebSvcReqWriter.close();
        infWebSvcReplyReader.close();
        httpUrlConnInfWebSvc.disconnect();
        //System.out.println(infWebSvcReplyString);

        return infWebSvcReplyString ;

        }
    }
```

Servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String id = request.getParameter("IdNumber");
        MessageConnector connector = new MessageConnector();
        String responsemessage = connector.callService(id);     
        System.out.println(responsemessage);
        request.setAttribute("responsemessage", responsemessage); 
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/NewFile.jsp").forward(request, response);

        doGet(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: Let's see what you've tried so far, show us your code. Programmers like code

Comment: Here, posted the code! I am just getting reponse for this one request because I have hard coded. But i want to remove the hard-coding and need an approach where I can call all the 4 soap requests.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you don't want to create the SOAP XML yourself.

The common approach is to use a framework that takes a WSDL, and generate stubs for it, and use calls to the stubs in your code.

The stubs and the framework handle all the protocol stuff, including generating the XML from the java objects.

[Axis2](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html) is such a framework for Java.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting. Is there a real implementation example for this. Please can you share it.